# ¿Cómo funcionan los atributos de sesión en Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Necesito obtener los datos del cliente que está logueado en mi página web con tal de cuando guarde los presupuestos de obra en mi base de datos, los guarde asignados al cliente logueado.

En mi aplicación, los clientes podrán hacer presupuestos de cada uno de los tipos de obra indicados. Entonces por sesión enviaré los datos del cliente y los de las obras, que estarán cargados en la vista final

Este es el controlador final:

```
    @Controller
    public class PresupuestoController {
    
        @Autowired
        private PresupuestoService presupuestoService;
    
        @Autowired
        private ObraNuevaService obraNuevaService;
    
        @Autowired
        private ReformaService reformaService;
    
        @Autowired
        private AseosService aseosService;
    
        @Autowired
        private CocinaService cocinaService;
    
        @GetMapping("/shop")
        public String tienda(Model model) {
            Presupuesto presupuesto = null;
            ObraNueva obranueva = new ObraNueva();
            Aseos aseos = new Aseos();
            Cocina cocina = new Cocina();
            model.addAttribute("presupuesto", presupuesto);
            model.addAttribute("obranueva", obranueva);
            model.addAttribute("aseos", aseos);
            model.addAttribute("cocina", cocina);
            return "haztupresupuesto";
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/list")
        public String listado() {
            return "presupuestos";
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/finishPresupuesto")
        public String finPresupuesto() {
            return "encargarpresupuesto";
        }
    
        @PostMapping("/newObra")
        public String nuevaObra(@Valid ObraNueva obranueva, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                model.addAttribute("obranueva", obranueva);
                return "haztupresupuesto";
            }
    
            if (obranueva instanceof Presupuesto) {
                obranueva.setTotal(obranueva.getSuperficie() * 1100 * obranueva.getCalidad());
            }
    
            obraNuevaService.save(obranueva);
            return "redirect:/finishPresupuesto";
        }
    
        @PostMapping("/newReformaAseo")
        public String nuevaReformaAseos(@Valid Aseos aseos, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                model.addAttribute("aseos", aseos);
                return "haztupresupuesto";
            }
    
            if (aseos instanceof Reforma) {
                reformaService.save(aseos);
            }
    
            if (aseos instanceof Presupuesto) {
                aseos.setTotal(2 * (aseos.getLargo() + aseos.getAncho()) * aseos.getAlto() + (aseos.getAncho() * aseos.getLargo()) * 50 + aseos.getPrecio_azulejo_m2() + (aseos.getAncho() * aseos.getLargo()) * 35 + aseos.getNum_sanitarios() + aseos.getModif_instalacion());
            }
    
            aseosService.save(aseos);
            return "redirect:/finishPresupuesto";
        }
    
        @PostMapping("/newReformaCocina")
        public String nuevaReformaCocina(@Valid Cocina cocina, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                model.addAttribute("cocina", cocina);
                return "haztupresupuesto";
            }
    
            if (cocina instanceof Reforma) {
                reformaService.save(cocina);
            }
            
            if (cocina instanceof Presupuesto) {
                cocina.setTotal(2 * (cocina.getLargo() + cocina.getAncho()) * cocina.getAlto() + (cocina.getAncho() * cocina.getLargo()) * 50 + cocina.getPrecio_azulejo_m2() + (cocina.getAncho() * cocina.getLargo()) * 35 + (cocina.getMueble_mtr_lineales() * 80) + (cocina.getEncimera_mtr_lineales() * 150) + cocina.getModif_instalacion());
            }
            
            cocinaService.save(cocina);
            return "redirect:/finishPresupuesto";
        }
    
        public String nuevoPresupuesto(Presupuesto presupuesto, ObraNueva obranueva, Aseos aseos, Cocina cocina,
                Model model) {
    
            presupuestoService.save(presupuesto);
            return "redirect:/list";
        }
    
    }
```

Aquí es donde necesito obtener la info del usuario logueado. ¿Cómo puedo cargar los datos del mismo y enviárselos a la vista?  Y otra duda, ¿cómo envío por sesión los objetos de tipo Presupuesto a la vista final para allí cargarlos y que se vean algunos de ellos por pantalla?

Comment: Hola Ismael, te sugiero que elimines de tu pregunta, las clases **Presupuesto , Reforma, ObraNueva, Aseo, Cocina y cliente**, ya que no son necesarias para darte una respuesta, en cambio, sería interesante ver tu clase **main** (o como se llame).

Comment: Okey, bueno al ser Spring Boot la clase main es la que va con una anotacion @SpringBootApplication y no se si es esa la que necesitas. Mi aplicación se despliega por tomcat en eclipse y funciona parecido a Spring MVC, en lo que a estructura se refiere. Dispone de controller, service, repository, domain, security. Soy un poco novatillo en esto, ¿que clase necesitas?

Comment: Actualmente esta pregunta incluye múltiples preguntas en una. Debería centrarse en un solo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, la situación es la siguiente:

En el controlador de arriba es donde tengo que recibir y enviar objetos como atributos de sesión, porque al hacer post, estos van a aparecer en otra pantalla.

Pero al ejecutarlo por post estos métodos, me retornan el siguiente error:

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'cocina' available as request attribute
```

El controlador está indicado arriba, mientras que en mi vista aparece lo siguiente:

Tengo 3 formularios, y en todos ellos hago llamada a los objetos que quiero enviar por sesión.

```
<div class="collapse">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <p><b>F&oacute;rmula:</b> <br>2 * (ancho + largo) * alto + (ancho * largo) * 50 + precio_azulejo + (ancho * largo) * 35 + Nº sanitarios + Modificaci&oacute;n instalaciones</p>
                                        <form id="formReformaAseo" action="#" th:action="@{/newReformaAseo}" th:object="${aseos}" method="POST">
                                            <fieldset>
                                                <div>
                                                    <img th:src="@{/images/bano.jpeg}" style="width: 300px; margin: auto; display: block;"><br>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                                            <label class="panel-title">Dimensiones: (largo X ancho X alto)</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                            <label>Largo:</label>
                                                            <input th:field="*{largo}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="largo"/><br>
                                                            <label>Ancho:</label>
                                                            <input th:field="*{ancho}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="ancho"/><br>
                                                            <label>Alto:</label>
                                                            <input th:field="*{alto}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="alto"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
    
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Nº sanitarios:</label><br>
                                                    <input th:field="*{num_sanitarios}" type="radio" id="cero" value="0">
                                                    <label for="cero">0</label>
                                                    <input th:field="*{num_sanitarios}" type="radio" id="uno" value="300">
                                                    <label for="uno">1</label>
                                                    <input th:field="*{num_sanitarios}" type="radio" id="dos" value="650">
                                                    <label for="dos">2</label>
                                                    <input th:field="*{num_sanitarios}" type="radio" id="tres" value="800">
                                                    <label for="tres">3</label>
                                                    <input th:field="*{num_sanitarios}" type="radio" id="cuatro" value="950">
                                                    <label for="cuatro">4</label>
                                                </div>
    
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Precio azulejo (€/m2):</label><br>
                                                    <input th:field="*{precio_azulejo_m2}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="precio_azulejo" />
                                                </div>
    
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Modificacion instalaciones:</label><br>
                                                    <input th:field="*{modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="ceroM" value="0">
                                                    <label for="ceroM">No</label>
                                                    <input th:field="*{modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="unoM" value="225">
                                                    <label for="unoM">1</label>
                                                    <input th:field="*{modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="dosM" value="350">
                                                    <label for="dosM">2</label>
                                                    <input th:field="*{modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="tresM" value="475">
                                                    <label for="tresM">3</label>
                                                    <input th:field="*{modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="cuatroM" value="600">
                                                    <label for="cuatroM">4</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                                        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" form="formReformaAseo" type="reset" value="Vaciar campos">
                                        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success" form="formReformaAseo" type="submit" value="Calcular presupuesto">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Este primero envía los datos de una reforma de aseo.

Este de abajo, envía los datos de una reforma de cocina.

```
<div class="collapse">
                                    <div class="panel-body ">
                                        <p><b>F&oacute;rmula:</b> <br>2 * (ancho+largo) * alto + (ancho * largo) * 50 + Precio azulejo + (ancho * largo) * 35 + Muebles, metros lineales + Encimera, metros lineales + Modificaci&oacute;n instalaciones</p>
                                        <form id="formReformaCocina" action="#" th:action="@{/newReformaCocina}" th:object="${cocina}" method="POST">
                                            <fieldset>
                                                <div>
                                                    <img th:src="@{/images/cocina.jpeg}" style="width: 300px; margin: auto; display: block;"><br>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                                            <label class="panel-title">Dimensiones: (largo X ancho X alto)</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                            <label>Largo (m):</label>
                                                            <input th:field="*{largo}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="largoCocina"/><br>
                                                            <label>Ancho (m):</label>
                                                            <input th:field="*{ancho}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="anchoCocina"/><br>
                                                            <label>Alto:</label>
                                                            <input th:field="*{alto}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="altoCocina"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
            
                                                <label>Muebles, metros lineales:</label><br>
                                                <input th:field="*{mueble_mtr_lineales}" class="form-control" type="number" id="muebles"/><br>
            
                                                <label>Encimera, metros lineales:</label><br>
                                                <input th:field="*{encimera_mtr_lineales}" class="form-control" type="number" id="encimera"/><br>
            
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Precio azulejo (€/m2):</label><br>
                                                    <input th:field="*{precio_azulejo_m2}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="precio_azulejo_cocina"/>
                                                </div>
            
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Modificacion instalaciones:</label><br>
                                                    <input th:field="*{modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="milCocina" value="1000">
                                                    <label for="milCocina">1000</label><br>
                                                    <input th:field="*{modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="ceroCocina" value="0">
                                                    <label for="ceroCocina">No</label><br>
                                                </div>
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                                        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" form="formReformaCocina" type="reset" value="Vaciar campos">
                                        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success" form="formReformaCocina" type="submit" value="Calcular presupuesto">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Y este es el que envía el objeto obranueva.

```
<div class="panel-body">
                            <form id="formObra" action="#" th:action="@{/newObra}" th:object="${obranueva}" method="POST">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <p><b>F&oacute;rmula:</b> <br>Superficie total a construir (m2) * 1100€/m2 * Calidad material (baja/media/alta)</p>
        
                                    <div>
                                        <img th:src="@{/images/obra.png}" style="width: 250px; margin: auto; display: block;"><br><br>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Superficie total a construir (m2):</label><br>
                                        <input th:field="*{superficie}" class="form-control" type="number" id="superficie" />
                                        <div class="alert alert-warning text-center" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('superficie')}" th:errors="*{superficie}"></div>
                                    </div>
        
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="calidad">Calidad material:</label><br>
                                        <input th:field="*{calidad}" type="radio" id="baja"  value="0.8">
                                        <label for="baja">Baja</label><br>
                                        <input th:field="*{calidad}" type="radio" id="media"  value="1">
                                        <label for="media">Media</label><br>
                                        <input th:field="*{calidad}" type="radio" id="alta"  value="1.3">
                                        <label for="alta">Alta</label><br>
                                        <div class="alert alert-warning text-center" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('calidad')}" th:errors="*{calidad}"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" type="reset" value="Vaciar campos">
                                        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" value="Calcular presupuesto">
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

Les pongo el mismo nombre a los parámetros y en mi controlador también dispone el objeto el mismo que en el atributo th:object.

¿Qué puedo hacer para corregir este error?